# Trying to get property of non-object in stdclass object

Tags: php, object, stdclass

I'm trying to integrate with an API. Assuming the following code works.

```
$lists = $ac->api("list/list_", array("ids" => "all"));

            echo"<pre>"; print_r( $lists); echo"</pre>";
```

Outputs the following stdclass object

```
stdClass Object
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => List 3
            [cdate] => 2018-02-27 08:19:39
            [private] => 0
            [userid] => 1
            [subscriber_count] => 0
        )

    [result_code] => 1
    [result_message] => Success: Something is returned
    [result_output] => json
    [http_code] => 200
    [success] => 1
)
```

The following code

```
            foreach($lists as $list) {

                   echo $list->id;

               }
```

Shows me an error

```
Trying to get property of non-object
```

The line $list->id is wrong. How can I fix this?

Comment: `var_dump($list)`, you'll discover that it is `1` at some point…

Comment: Can you clarify? Not sure how this helps.

Comment: If you did `foreach ($lists as $key => $list)`, then `$key` will be `0`, `result_code`, `result_message`, etc. Does that help?

Comment: How would that be written as code?

Comment: You don't need to write it as code. The problem is that the object which has an `->id` property is at the same level as other values such as `1`, `"Success: Something is returned"` etc, and you're trying to access `->id` on all of those diverse values.

Comment: You should really be changing your API so it returns something like `[results] => Array ( [0] => ... ), [result_code] => ...`, that's much easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an odd structure, whats happening is its looping over `result_code`, `result_message`, `result_output`, `success` which the values are not objects.

Either fix that, or do a check in the loop of sorts.

```
foreach ($lists as $key => $list) {
    if (!is_numeric($key) || !is_object($list)) {
        continue;
    }
    echo $list->id;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
foreach($lists as $list) {
       $list = (array)$list;
       if(isset($list['id'])){
           echo $list['id'];
       }
}
```

Comment: You don't need to cast to an array in order to use `isset`.

Comment: I think you had better handle results in 'list/list_' api first check $lists has result or counter...

Answer (score 0):

PHP Objects are clean and easy to write.

// Echoing a PHP Array value

```
echo $array['value'];
```

// Echoing a PHP Object value

```
echo $object->value;
```

Now to the conversion (casting) of a PHP Array into a PHP Object. This is very simple. I just type cast the Array as an Object when returning it.

```
function array_to_object($array) {
    return (object) $array;
}
```

The above is just an example. You do not need a PHP function to convert an Array into an Object. The (object) function will do that to any PHP Array. If you ever need to change an Object into an Array, then use the (array) type casting function.

```
function object_to_array($object) {
    return (array) $object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When return data from json where [ ] is not present, do a array before parsing your data. 
Like the sample:

```
foreach(array($YourData) as $row){
    echo $row->ValueOfYourData;
}
```